# Checking for objects in an array

Tags: php

I'm querying, via soap client and PHP, a database that returns the following output;

```
$response = $client->executeSQLQuery(array("sql"=>$sql));

object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["return"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["row"]=>
    array(276) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
        ["applicationuser"]=>
        string(7) "rmjtapi"
        ["device"]=>
        string(15) "SEP111111111111"
        ["devicedescription"]=>
        string(27) "User 1"
        ["permissiongroup"]=>
        string(20) "Standard CTI Enabled"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (4) {
        ["applicationuser"]=>
        string(7) "rmjtapi"
        ["device"]=>
        string(15) "SEP222222222222"
        ["devicedescription"]=>
        string(13) "User 2"
        ["permissiongroup"]=>
        string(20) "Standard CTI Enabled"
      }
```

I would like to verify that a device, SEP111111111111, exists in the array.  It looks like I can use the in_array function to do this but I can't get it to work;

```
if (in_array("SEP111111111111", $response)))
        {
        echo "True";
        }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `array_column()` on your nested property and then use `in_array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($response->return->row as $value) {
    if ($value->device === 'SEP111111111111') {
        echo 'True';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it our with this:

```
$primary_array = $response->return->row;
foreach($primary_array as $a){
    if($a->device == 'SEP111111111111'){
        echo "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, each of these works.  Much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general function you can use to accomplish this.  Please note that the `isset()` checks are important, since you should almost always verify the structure of the response data before attempting to consume its values.

```
function deviceIdExistsInResponse(\stdClass $response, $deviceIdToSeek) {
    if (!isset($response->return->row)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($response->return->row as $row) {
        if (isset($row->device) && $row->device == $deviceIdToSeek) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Usage:
$deviceIdToSeek           = 'SEP111111111111';
$deviceIdExistsInResponse = deviceIdExistsInResponse($response, deviceIdToSeek);
echo $deviceIdToSeek . ' ' . ($deviceIdExistsInResponse ? 'located' : 'not found');
```